# How to split a text file which is having '\t' and ',' values in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I want to convert text file which is having tab and comma separated values into fully comma separated value in PIG. I am using Apache Pig version 0.11.1., I have tried with the following code and tried with FLATTEN, TOKENIZE. But I cannot make it into fully CSV file.

```
a = load '/home/mansoor/Documents/ip.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (key:chararray, val1:chararray, val2:chararray );  

b = FOREACH a {  
  key= STRSPLIT(key,'\t');  
  GENERATE key;  
}
```

Following is my text file input:

```
M12345  M123456,M234567,M987653  
M23456  M23456,M123456,M234567  
M34567  M234567,M765678,M987643
```

I need a file which is having fully CSV file like the following output:

```
M12345,M123456,M234567,M987653  
M23456,M23456,M123456,M234567  
M34567,M234567,M765678,M987643
```

How can I do this?

Comment: a= load '/home/mansoor/Documents/ip.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (key:chararray, val1:chararray, val2:chararray );                   b = FOREACH a{
  key= STRSPLIT(key,'\t');
  GENERATE key;
}.. i tried with STRSPLIT,TOKENIZE but i cant make it into fully csv file..can you tell the simple way to split into fully csv file please?

Comment: If your problem is solved, please do not forget to accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

With pig 0.13, just using `load` without `PigStorage` made the csv be well loaded.

```
a = load '/home/mansoor/Documents/ip.txt';
dump a
```

gives me

```
(M12345,M123456,M234567,M987653)
(M23456,M23456,M123456,M234567)
(M34567,M234567,M765678,M987643 )
```

If that's not what you want, you might want to consider the [`REPLACE`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/func.html#replace) function.
Here is a quick and dirty solution to dispose of a usable csv :

```
a = load '/home/mansoor/Documents/ip.txt' using PigStorage('\n');
b = foreach a generate FLATTEN(REPLACE($0, '\t', ','));
store b into 'tmp.csv';
```

You can then use the csv as intended :

```
c = load 'tmp.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (key:chararray, val1:chararray, val2:chararray, val3:chararray);
describe c
```

gives `c: {key: chararray,val1: chararray,val2: chararray, val3:chararray}`

Comment: if i try b = foreach a generate replace($0, '\t', ','); it showing error like could not resolve replace using import.

Comment: Thank you so much. its working. But if i describe c its look like a empty tuple. If i want to get $0 and $2 from c mean it showing error like out of bound access.How to solve this?

Comment: What is the output of `dump c` ?

Comment: output of c: ((M12345,M123456,M234567,M987653))
((M23456,M23456,M123456,M234567))
((M34567,M234567,M765678,M987643)). if i try to get $0 and $2 from c using  d = foreach c generate $0 ,$2 i got out of bound access error.but i need a file which will be access easily like normal CSV file M12345,M123456,M234567,M987653 like this..

Comment: @Karthick I posted a quick and dirty workaround. I'll update my answer when I'll find something nicer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
a = load '/home/mansoor/Documents/ip.txt';

store a into '/home/mansoor/Documents/op' using PigStorage(',');
```

Now the file is fully converted into csv file.